# Are there Low level Swift classes to upload files in AWS S3

Tags: java, ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is the same code in Java was wondering if they have a swift equivalent, which
allows you to break up files into parts:

long partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

```
        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                                    .build();

            List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();


            InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucketName, keyName);
            InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

            long filePosition = 0;
            for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
                partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));


                UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                        .withBucketName(bucketName)
                        .withKey(keyName)
                        .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
                        .withPartNumber(i)
                        .withFileOffset(filePosition)
                        .withFile(file)
                        .withPartSize(partSize);

                UploadPartResult uploadResult = s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
                partETags.add(uploadResult.getPartETag());

                filePosition += partSize;
            }


            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucketName, keyName,
                    initResponse.getUploadId(), partETags);
            s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
        }
```

Comment: The code shown above is either part of a third party library or custom code. It is not part of Java and there is no built in support for AWS in Swift either. What you are probably looking for is the [AWS iOS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) which you can import into your project and use.

Comment: This code is from the AWS website so I know this is not custom code. So I am still asking the question I have obviously looked on the AWS Website and have the SDK other wise i wouldn't be able to use AWS properly with my app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AWSS3` client from AWSiOSSDKv2 here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios

The request which you are looking for is this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSS3/AWSS3Model.h#L6618 and can be used be invoked via this API: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSS3/AWSS3Service.h#L1994